# Storage not recoverable

Tags: storage, file-system

Are there any known conditions where an update results in irrecoverable storage?  I am asking this because an Android device has lost storage and I have been unsuccessful in recovering 3GB.

Comment: Update to what? Stock ROM? Custom?

Comment: OS update.   To 6.0